# Google Music API: how to request the next 1000 songs?

Tags: api, curl, google-music

I'm trying to figure out how to use Google Music API. I managed to get the auth token as described in http://dpogue.ca/gmusic.html:

```
$ curl -d accountType=GOOGLE
       -d Email=jondoe@gmail.com    
       -d Passwd=<<PASSWORD>>
       -d service=sj
       https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin

SID=DQB...
LSID=DQC...
Auth=DQA...
```

Now I'm able to request the list of tracks in my library:

```
$ curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQA..."     
       https://www.googleapis.com/sj/v1beta1/tracks > list
```

However, it only returns a list of 1000 tracks.

```
$ grep -c albumArtist list
1000
```

How do I request the next 1000 tracks? I've tried to append the nextPageToken to the URL:

```
$ grep nextPage list
"nextPageToken": "KmM...AI="
$ curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQA..."     
       https://www.googleapis.com/sj/v1beta1/tracks?pageToken=KmM...AI= > list2
```

but I just get the same first 1000 tracks.

How do I tell googleapis.com to return the next bunch?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your password supposed to be visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I was advised to use a different URL: https://www.googleapis.com/sj/v1beta1/trackfeed

The correct way to provide nextPageToken to the second request is now to send it per POST as JSON:

```
$ curl
  --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQA..."     
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
  --data "{'start-token': 'KmM...'}
  "https://www.googleapis.com/sj/v1beta1/trackfeed
  > list2
```

For me it turned out to be even easier to request all tracks at once by providing

```
  --data "{'max-results': '20000'}
```

Thanks to Darryl Pogue from http://dpogue.ca/!

Comment: do you know how to do this with plistentry?  I'm getting an error when I try and send it that same max-results data.